# bind port 80 to non root user. CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, shoutcast

I need to Allow port 80 access to non privileged User on my CentOs. I am running Shoutcast, and Centova Cast on my server to host audio streams. I have been using port 80 for the last few months now without a problem using the following.....

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 5.10.69.104 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.70.106.130:8000
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 5.10.69.105 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.70.106.130:8002
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 5.10.69.106 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.70.106.130:8004
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 5.10.69.107 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.70.106.130:8006
```

I am currently testing my new Centova Cast control panel using the last IP address listed (5.10.69.107). I am not able to reach my audio stream using Centova Cast using port 80. the other 3 streams are working using root access.

Using the suggestions on this page https://secure.centova.com/pages/faqs/display/using_port_80_for_streaming_121 I have attempted setcap with the following

```
     setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /home/centovacast/shoutcast/sc_serv
and 

    setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /home/centovacast/vhosts/bcr64k/etc/server.conf
and
     setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /home/centovacast/system/runascc/castd
```

with no effect. Am I missing something? the actual test process that is running on the server for Centova cast looks like this.

/home/centovacast/system/runascc/castd 
/home/centovacast/shoutcast/sc_serv /home/centovacast/vhosts/bcr64k/etc/server.conf

If working properly, you should be able to hear music in a media player using 5.10.69.107. it currently works on 5.10.69.104 , 105, and 106. All addresses are on the same server, with the audio coming from the same source. 
Any suggestions would help. Thank you
-Bob Swaggerty

Answer (score 1):

Resolved

I needed to remove from Iptables

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 5.10.69.104 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.70.106.130:8000
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 5.10.69.105 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.70.106.130:8002
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 5.10.69.106 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.70.106.130:8004
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 5.10.69.107 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.70.106.130:8006
```

and replace with

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 5.10.69.104 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 5.10.69.105 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8002
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 5.10.69.106 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8004
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 5.10.69.107 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8006
```